# What does it mean if a medical faculty doesn't have "standard medical facilities"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, medical

As English is not my first language, I'm not sure what this means. I've come across a [post on a forum](https://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/what-about-serbia.466652/#post-5818271) saying that some medical schools don't have "standard medical facilities". Here's the whole sentence:

> I personally wouldn't advice bulgaria, ukraine, serbia, and the other eastern european countries coz i've heard that they don't have standard medical facilities (and the language barrier is even worse).

I'm not sure what exactly that is referring to. Does that mean that the standard of those facilities is poor, or that they don't have a specific standard regarding their medical facilities, or something else?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid without context, we have absolutely no way of knowing what meaning was intended, only that the medical facilities are not "standard" in some unspecified way. It could mean the walls are painted fluorescent purple for all we know. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance on writing good, answerable questions. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: OK, I had in mind  this post https://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/what-about-serbia.466652/#post-5818271. I didn't want to spam the forum with what-I-thought was an unnecessary information, so I didn't include the whole context.

Comment: Did you mean to write 'faculties'? Also, the singular of 'facilities' is 'facility'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 - When OP wrote "faculties" what was meant was "schools" or "departments."  I understood this right away because in Spanish, the word for "academic department" is "facultad," which is a false cognate.  One sees this false cognate frequently here at Academia SE and I've gotten used to it here.

Comment: Oh, no. He didn't say "faculties", but "facilities". According to Wiktionary a facility means an institution. So he probably meant health care institutions. But what the word "standard" means in "standard medical facilities" - associated clinics?

Comment: By the way, I didn't mean that user9825893y50932 said "facilites" instead of "faculties", but the one from the other forum at the top.

Comment: Aleksa, here is the original sentence that is giving some trouble.  This is what you originally wrote: *some medical faculties don't have "standard medical facilities*.  I edited your question and replaced "medical faculties" with "medical schools."  I did not change any of the words in the phrase "standard medical facilities."  There was no need to. Please note that in my answer, I provided a dictionary definition of "medical *facilities*."  I feel confident that when you wrote "medical *faculties*," you were comparing *medical schools*.

Answer (score 0):

> some medical faculties don't have "standard medical facilities"

I'll describe an analogous situation: imagine an agronomy department with a course about how to do maintenance on a tractor to keep it running well, but there's no tractor on campus and no access to a farm with a tractor on it.  The students never have a chance to see an internal combustion engine.  Their learning would be purely theoretical, and the students would be limited in what they'd be able to do with tractors after taking the course.

If a certain medical school (that's a synonym for this way of using "faculty") doesn't have a clinical training component, because it isn't associated with any sort of clinic, then the students will be quite limited in what they're getting from their medical training.

Note, *facility* has been defined ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/facility)) as

> 2. often facilities
>
>    a. A building, room, array of equipment, or a number of such things, designed to serve a particular function: *hospitals and other health care facilities.*

In the context of the forum post you read, the medical facilities one would need in order to set up an effective medical school would include exam rooms, exam beds, a medical lab, an x-ray machine, an ultrasound machine, a system for organizing and storing charts (paper or electronic), a way of communicating with external medical facilities, an operating room, equipment for sterilizing instruments, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Our School of Medicine is associated with the local group of hospitals from various specialties, some of them are excellent, and the others are not in such good condition. However, clinical practice is very important aspect for studying medicine, and there are certainly other schools that are more committed to  providing their students more and better practice.

Comment: @AleksaLukić - Well, one thing is commitment, and another, sometimes separate thing, is facilities.  I had the experience, in the Third World, of trying to understand how the internal combustion engine works and how to maintain a tractor, in a class that was taught entirely on a chalkboard.  The teacher meant well, but was held back by the lack of standard agricultural facilities.

Comment: Aham. So in this context "facilities" mean equipment?

Comment: @AleksaLukić - Yes, along with the building, furniture, charts, and necessary personnel.

Comment: What is a medical faculty? For me, that means medical professors....professors who teach medicine at a college/university....

Comment: @Lambie - Please look at the edit history and my comments below the question.

Comment: Ah right, well, I would have changed it to medical school, for AmE anyway.

Comment: @Lambie - Um, that's what I did.  The relevant sentence in the question now says *I've come across a post on a forum saying that some medical schools don't have "standard medical facilities."*

Comment: Why is it so impossible to make a comment? I saw your block quote. The asker uses faculty in the singular, which, can, at times, mean school, like in French or Spanish or Portuguese.  Personally, I don't use it.

Comment: @Lambie - I'm lost.  Help me out, please.  Why do you say it's impossible to make a comment?  // Do you agree or disagree with my edit to the question, to change "faculty" to "school" -- I can't tell.  // *Personally, I don't use it.* I didn't think you would.  I'm really not sure what you're getting at....

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "standard" is being used with the following definition from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standard#Adjective)

> 4. Of a usable or serviceable grade or quality.

This adjective is related to the noun form:

> 1.1. A level of quality or attainment.

So what it's saying is that the medical facilities in these countries don't generally meet the level of quality that we considered minimally acceptable in the west.